# Keycloak Realm per Project

Tags: server, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

I having a usecase like in the picture below, where I have many projects (~ 1000) of the same application but on different servers/endpoints. Normal-Users should only be allowed to login to the projects they belong. But there should also exists Super-Users and Admins which should be allowed to accesss more than one or all projects.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FZak.png)

I thought about using Keycloak for that. My idea was to create a Realm for every project. So every project has its own users and there is no way user-1 from project-1 could access project-2. Then create some super-users and admins which are allowed to login to more projects. I am not very familiar with keycloak for now because I am only using one Realm to auth from an app. So I am not really sure if this even is the right approach or if there is an easier or better way.

I also read that keycloak has problems if you use more than 200 realms. Probably this could be fixed with a load balancer. Where Project 1-100 goes to Keycloak-Instance-1 and Project 101-200 to Keycloak-Instance-2. This would also minimize a complete failure of the system.

So my question is, is my suggested approach right or how could i also achive this?

Comment: you could check https://github.com/p2-inc/keycloak-orgs which is a open source keycloak extension providing multi-tenancy  features. it uses one realm only. within the realm you can create "organizations" with distinct users, etc. You can map organizations and their roles to token claims with a built-in mapper.

Comment: Hi, thanks i will have a look at this.

Comment: You can also watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTFlc-3pG1M to get some background information.